# mean by subgroup of a group

Tags: r, aggregate, mean, levels

I have data with the following 3 Variables of interest (Kanton, Öffentlich_Privat, Value)
Kanton has 26 Levels, Öffenlich_Privat has 2 Levels. I would now like to aggregate the sum for every canton per level of Öffentlich Privat. I knwo the code to do it per group, but how to do it two levels down?

```
aggregate(data$Wert, list(data$Kanton), mean)

  > head(data)
 Jahr Forstzone  Kanton         Eigentümertyp               Variable    Wert Privat_Öffentlich
1: 1975   Schweiz Schweiz Eigentümertyp - Total  Anzahl Waldeigentümer  261471             Total
2: 1975   Schweiz Schweiz Eigentümertyp - Total    Gesamte Waldflächen 1114137             Total
3: 1975   Schweiz Schweiz Eigentümertyp - Total Produktive Waldflächen  978221             Total
4: 1975   Schweiz Schweiz          Privatwälder  Anzahl Waldeigentümer  257722            Privat
5: 1975   Schweiz Schweiz          Privatwälder    Gesamte Waldflächen  297443            Privat
6: 1975   Schweiz Schweiz          Privatwälder Produktive Waldflächen  297443            Privat
```

Comment: Waht is your expected output

Comment: as in the help of aggregate stated: `by = a list of grouping elements`. Simply add both factors in the the list: `list(data$Kanton, data$Öffentlich Privat)`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(`Öffentlich Privat`, Kanton) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Value, na.rm=TRUE))
```